# Use of "patterned" as a synonym for "modeling" or "simulated"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm a beginner in English, and I'm  writing a academic paper.
Could someone please clarify if the use of word **patterned** function as a good synonym for **modeling** or **simulated** in the following sentence?

> Aiming to test the reproducibility of the present modeling setup were **patterned** three realistic spills occurred in the region.

Comment: Do you mean **....setup where patterned....** or **.....when patterned...** Even with these changes, the expression is not clear.

Comment: Please provide some context - what are you talking/writing about?

Comment: modeling set-up is pretty much nonsensical here.

Comment: What are you actually trying to say?

Comment: @Lambie IMO it was making sense *up to and including* the word "setup." After that, it makes some sort of sense if you change the word order to "... setup, three realistic spills occurring in the region were simulated" - but that's just a guess at what the OP was trying to write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I'd say no, **patterned** isn't really a good replacement here. **Patterned** indicates that you're copying something, but it does not indicate what you're doing with the copy. **Modelled** or **simulated** would both be better, but you could use either of those words *along with* **patterened**.

Second, the sentence structure is rather off. It took me a few read-throughs to understand it. I'd suggest switching it around a bit:

> Aiming to test the reproducibility of the present modelling setup, we ran **simulations patterned** on three spills that had occurred in the region

This indicates that you ran simulations, and that the simulations were copied from - or **patterned on** - spills that had really occurred.

Other uses of **patterned** in a similar context could be:

> Germany launched a blitzkrieg attack, **patterned on** their successful strike against Poland.
>
> A new product was designed, **patterned on** the most successful products of the last ten years.

In each case, **patterned** indicates that the action taken was being copied from something else, but **patterned** by itself does not indicate what action is being taken.

Comment: Patterned does not mean you are copying something. patterned x, is an x with a pattern. Patterned wall paper.

Comment: @Lambie yes, that is one *use* of 'patterned', but it's not the only use - and it derives from the idea of copying. A pattern is something repeated.

Comment: This might all be perfectly correct, but it *feels* like an assumption too far to me.

Comment: present modeling set-ups is a complete no go, afaic.

Comment: @Lambie what can't you understand about "present modelling set-ups"? It's a perfectly good phrase meaning the same as "the modelling scenarios that we are considering at this point in time" IMO.

Comment: @alephzero Modeling is to make a model of something. Test modeling; trial modeling, pattern modeling, mathematical modeling. There is no sense in saying "modeling set-up". It does not sound like professional, reproducibility. testing lingo. "My modeling set-up was all wrong." That is OK in speech. But not in a formal document. The OP's sentence is off. It's not about what I do not understand. It's about good writing.

Comment: A modeling set-up would be a set of tools and equipment, hardware or software, used to carry out modeling work. I don't see anything unprofessional or incorrect about it.

Comment: @Werrf And that is poor English. A set of tools and equipment is not a modeling set-up. A modeling set-up is not "a term". If I have a machine tool shop, I can say: I have a good set-up at my shop. Modeling is done using software programs and/or physical facilities. Here, take a read: https://www.ohmsett.com/research.html

Comment: @Lambie It may not be a term you personally would use; this is utterly irrelevant. It's perfectly acceptable English.

Comment: @Werrf It is not a technical term used in performing tests. It just is not. And your first blockquote sentence is not good technical English. It has nothing to do with me personally. Also the OP has not communicated anything more so we don't know if this is an **oil spill** or something else. The OP did say: I am a beginner in English.

Answer (score 3):

Aiming to test the reproducibility of the present modeling setup were patterned three realistic spills occurred in the region.

Rewritten:

To test the reproducibility of this model's hypothesis, the patterns of three realistic spills that occurred in the region were used.

The tests were patterned on the realistic spills that occurred in the region.

oil spill patterns or [water in rivers] spill patterns or leakage spill patterns

Comment: I disagree with this. IMO The OP is using "pattern" as a verb, not as a noun, as in https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pattern #2.1 - "Give something [the modeling set-up] a form based on that of something else [three realistic spills]."

Comment: The OP's sentence is gibberish. So,it's all a guessing game anyway. Modeling set-up is not used in formal documents like this. You can set  up an experiment.

Answer (score 2):

To "pattern" something after something else, means to structure it based on the *pattern* of that thing -- which is to say, its *outward* form.  Both "simulation" and "model" normally involve some kind of *pattern reproduction*, but do this with more fundamental elements or concepts.

For example, a meteorologist might use mathematical *models* (known formulas that describe air movement, pressure, precipitation, etc.) to create a hurricane *simulation*.   To test the simulation, the meteorologist might check that it accurately reproduces the *patterns* of past real-world hurricanes, given the same starting conditions and other controls.

To put it another way:  The *models* are the underlying data and mathematical structures that drive the *simulation*.  The *pattern* is the output from the simulations.  So when you *model/simulate* something you usually think about all the elements that make it work, but when you *pattern* something you simply copy its observed behavior.

All are valid scientific techniques, of course.  Sometimes *patterning* is all a researcher can do, until the underlying elements are better understood.